# Generate property file from Batch script

Tags: batch-file

I want to generate the property file in which data inside the file will be increment increasing using Batch scripting. I have to generate the 10 property file which incremental change in data.

I have property file `abpp_deploy.property` where the data is mentioned below:

```
    CHOSEN_INSTALL_SET=DEPLOYER
    I2_ABPP_BASE_WEB_URI=base
    I2_ABPP_BRE_PATH=D:\\JDA\\JDA2017_3\\config\\JDAv2017_SEMs1\\bre
    I2_ABPP_HOME=D:\\JDA\\JDA2017_3\\config\\JDAv2017_SEMs1
    I2_APPSERVER_PORT1=2000
    I2_APPSERVER_PORT2=15444
    I2_APP_FOLDER_NAME=SOP_-_SEMS
    I2_CIS_HOME=
    I2_DATABASE_TYPE=Oracle
    I2_DATA_POPULATION="","Skip automatic schema creation and data population."
    I2_DATA_POPULATION_TEXT_2=Create schema and populate with solution data.
    I2_DATA_POPULATION_TEXT_3=Skip automatic schema creation and data population.
    I2_DB2_DRIVER=com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver
    I2_DB2_HOME=C:\\Program Files\\IBM\\SQLLIB
    I2_DB2_HOST=DB2_HOST
    I2_DB2_INFO_1=
    I2_DB2_INFO_2=
    I2_DB2_INFO_2_XOR=
    I2_DB2_INFO_3=
    I2_DB2_INFO_4=
    I2_DB2_JARS=C:\\Program Files\\IBM\\SQLLIB\\java
    I2_DB2_JAR_1=db2jcc.jar
    I2_DB2_JAR_2=db2jcc_license_cu.jar
    I2_DB2_PORT=50000
    I2_DEPLOY_JAR=SEMS.jar
    I2_DEPLOY_JAR_PATH_OF_SELECTED_FILE=D:\\Installer\\jdaplatform-2017.1.0.25-windows\\abpp\\installers
    I2_DEPLOY_TYPE=STANDALONE
    I2_DEPLOY_WEBCLIENT=
    I2_EMAIL_ENABLED=
    I2_EMAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=sysadmin@mycompany.com
    I2_EMAIL_SMTP_HOST=smtp.mycompany.com
    I2_EMAIL_SYS_USER_ADDRESS=sysadmin@mycompany.com
    I2_ENCRYPT=true
    I2_INSTALL_PROD=Prod
    I2_JDK_HOME=D:\\Java8\\jdk1.8.0_181
    I2_LICENSE_FILE=D:\\license\\PSA100417.lic
    I2_LICENSE_FILE_LOCATION=D:\\license
    I2_LICENSE_FILE_NAME=PSA100417.lic
    I2_ORACLE_DRIVER=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
    I2_ORACLE_HOME=D:\\Oracle64\\product\\12.1.0\\client_1
    I2_ORACLE_HOST=sl1psadevdb2v.jdadelivers.com
    I2_ORACLE_INFO_1=ABPPMGR
    I2_ORACLE_INFO_2={E:AES}6AA9880B2F94C92CA09E7665CC4AA76B
    I2_ORACLE_INFO_2_XOR=@CQQLFS
    I2_ORACLE_INFO_3=PSADVDB
    I2_ORACLE_INFO_4=
    I2_ORACLE_JAR=D:\\Oracle64\\product\\12.1.0\\client_1\\jdbc\\lib\\ojdbc7.jar
    I2_ORACLE_PORT=1521
    I2_PLATFORM_HOME=
    I2_WEBCLIENT_TYPE=NoWeb
    I2_WEBLOGIC_BASE_APP=D:\\JDA\\JDA2017_3\\config\\JDAv2017_SEMs1\\web\\base
    I2_WEBLOGIC_DOMAIN_HOME=C:\\bea\\user_projects\\domains\\mydomain
    I2_WEBSPHERE_APPNAME=
    I2_WEBSPHERE_APPNAME_BASE=base
    I2_WEBSPHERE_CONTEXTROOT=
    I2_WEBSPHERE_CONTEXTROOT_BASE=/base
    I2_WEBSPHERE_HOME=C:\\Program Files\\IBM\\WebSphere\\AppServer
    I2_WEBSPHERE_INSTALLABLE=
    I2_WEBSPHERE_NODE=
    I2_WEB_SERVER_PORT=22246
    INSTALLER_UI=SWING
    USER_INSTALL_DIR=D:\\JDA\\JDA2017_3\\config\\JDAv2017_SEMs1
```

Here I have to increment the data like first file value will be
    `USER_INSTALL_DIR=D:\\JDA\\JDA2017_3\\config\\JDAv2017_SEMs1 I2_WEB_SERVER_PORT=22246`

But the 2nd file which will be generated has the values like this:

```
USER_INSTALL_DIR=D:\\JDA\\JDA2017_3\\config\\JDAv2017_SEMs2
I2_WEB_SERVER_PORT=2224`
```

similarly 10 file generate where value will be change every time.

I have created one environment file `Batchenv.bat` which will call through one test.bat file

```
******************test.bat file code *****************
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
call %~dp0\Batchenv.bat

set sourcedir=C:\Users\1026478\Desktop\local

set envFile=%sourcedir%\Batchenv.bat

    IF EXIST %envFile% (
        call %envFile% 
    ) else (
        echo "Error:::::Environment file missing."
        exit /b 0
    )

    IF NOT EXIST %sourcedir%\abpp_deploy.Property (
        echo "ERROR: Property file does not exist or is not readable in below path.\n"
        echo %sourcedir%
        exit /b 1
    )

ECHO Env File check completed.


set "file_app=%sourcedir%\Batchenv.bat" 

    For /L %%A IN (1,1,1) DO (
            ECHO %%A
            set VAR1=%%A
        For /F "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("%file_app%") do (
            set VAR=%%a
            For /F "tokens=1* delims= " %%G IN ("!VAR!") DO (
                set NODE_VAR=%%G
                echo %%G %%H
                echo %%H|findstr /I /C:"JDAv2017_SEMs1"
                echo %%H>>newfile_!VAR1!.Property
            )
        )
    )


:: newfile.txt now contains a modified version.
:: This line will overwrite the original

::MOVE /y newfile.Property "%sourcedir%\abpp_deploy.Property"

GOTO :EOF




REM (for /F "delims=" %%F in (version-test.properties) do echo %%F | findstr /c:"test1=" /c:"test2=" /c:"test3=" /c:"test4=" >nul && (echo %%F | for /F "delims==" %%L in ('more') do @echo %%L=)  || echo %%F) > build-new.txt
```

*****************Batchenv.bat************************

```
    @echo off
    SET CHOSEN_INSTALL_SET=DEPLOYER
    SET I2_ABPP_BASE_WEB_URI=base
    SET I2_ABPP_BRE_PATH=D:\\JDA\\JDA2017_3\\config\\JDAv2017_SEMs1\\bre
    SET I2_ABPP_HOME=D:\\JDA\\JDA2017_3\\config\\JDAv2017_SEMs1
    SET I2_APPSERVER_PORT1=2000
    SET I2_APPSERVER_PORT2=15444
    SET I2_APP_FOLDER_NAME=SOP_-_SEMS
    SET I2_CIS_HOME=
    SET I2_DATABASE_TYPE=Oracle
    SET I2_DATA_POPULATION="","Skip automatic schema creation and data population."
    SET I2_DATA_POPULATION_TEXT_2=Create schema and populate with solution data.
    SET I2_DATA_POPULATION_TEXT_3=Skip automatic schema creation and data population.
    SET I2_DB2_DRIVER=com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver
    SET I2_DB2_HOME=C:\\Program Files\\IBM\\SQLLIB
    SET I2_DB2_HOST=DB2_HOST
    SET I2_DB2_INFO_1=
    SET I2_DB2_INFO_2=
    SET I2_DB2_INFO_2_XOR=
    SET I2_DB2_INFO_3=
    SET I2_DB2_INFO_4=
    SET I2_DB2_JARS=C:\\Program Files\\IBM\\SQLLIB\\java
    SET I2_DB2_JAR_1=db2jcc.jar
    SET I2_DB2_JAR_2=db2jcc_license_cu.jar
    SET I2_DB2_PORT=50000
    SET I2_DEPLOY_JAR=SEMS.jar
    SET I2_DEPLOY_JAR_PATH_OF_SELECTED_FILE=D:\\Installer\\jdaplatform-2017.1.0.25-windows\\abpp\\installers
    SET I2_DEPLOY_TYPE=STANDALONE
    SET I2_DEPLOY_WEBCLIENT=
    SET I2_EMAIL_ENABLED=
    SET I2_EMAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=sysadmin@mycompany.com
    SET I2_EMAIL_SMTP_HOST=smtp.mycompany.com
    SET I2_EMAIL_SYS_USER_ADDRESS=sysadmin@mycompany.com
    SET I2_ENCRYPT=true
    SET I2_INSTALL_PROD=Prod
    SET I2_JDK_HOME=D:\\Java8\\jdk1.8.0_181
    SET I2_LICENSE_FILE=D:\\license\\PSA100417.lic
    SET I2_LICENSE_FILE_LOCATION=D:\\license
    SET I2_LICENSE_FILE_NAME=PSA100417.lic
    SET I2_ORACLE_DRIVER=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
    SET I2_ORACLE_HOME=D:\\Oracle64\\product\\12.1.0\\client_1
    SET I2_ORACLE_HOST=sl1psadevdb2v.jdadelivers.com
    SET I2_ORACLE_INFO_1=ABPPMGR
    SET I2_ORACLE_INFO_2={E:AES}6AA9880B2F94C92CA09E7665CC4AA76B
    SET I2_ORACLE_INFO_2_XOR=@CQQLFS
    SET I2_ORACLE_INFO_3=PSADVDB
    SET I2_ORACLE_INFO_4=
    SET I2_ORACLE_JAR=D:\\Oracle64\\product\\12.1.0\\client_1\\jdbc\\lib\\ojdbc7.jar
    SET I2_ORACLE_PORT=1521
    SET I2_PLATFORM_HOME=
    SET I2_WEBCLIENT_TYPE=NoWeb
    SET I2_WEBLOGIC_BASE_APP=D:\\JDA\\JDA2017_3\\config\\JDAv2017_SEMs1\\web\\base
    SET I2_WEBLOGIC_DOMAIN_HOME=C:\\bea\\user_projects\\domains\\mydomain
    SET I2_WEBSPHERE_APPNAME=
    SET I2_WEBSPHERE_APPNAME_BASE=base
    SET I2_WEBSPHERE_CONTEXTROOT=
    SET I2_WEBSPHERE_CONTEXTROOT_BASE=/base
    SET I2_WEBSPHERE_HOME=C:\\Program Files\\IBM\\WebSphere\\AppServer
    SET I2_WEBSPHERE_INSTALLABLE=
    SET I2_WEBSPHERE_NODE=
    SET I2_WEB_SERVER_PORT=22246
    SET INSTALLER_UI=SWING
    SET USER_INSTALL_DIR=D:\\JDA\\JDA2017_3\\config\\JDAv2017_SEMs1
```

I am able to generate the file with constant value but not able to incremental change it.

Comment: I have attempted to fix your formatting and grammar to make the question more understandable. If you feel I have gone too far please [edit] it to clarify what it is you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I've also had a shot at amending this question to improve readability.

There's alot that's Not right with your code @Priyanka Pandey. As for what (I think) your trying to do, I strongly suggest you look at: `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166386/arrays-linked-lists-and-other-data-structures-in-cmd-exe-batch-script` For tips on how to Build arrays in Batch to proccess Information in terms of var[1] var[2] var[3] etc, also, adjust your usage of `For /L` Loops to much the number of data sets to be handled. EG- If your handling 100 data sets, you would use `For /L %%I in (1,1,100) Do (`